# How to make bold words in text (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I want to make bold to some words in text. But before ":" 
how can i do this with php

Samle Text

```
Dimensions Width: 940mm(37-1/8”)
Height: 106mm(4-1/4”)
Depth: 317mm(12-1/2”)
Weight: 4.0kg

Control Interface
Keyboard Number of Keys: 61
Display Type: LCD display
Language: English
```

I wanto to sample result
**Dimensions**
**Width:** 940mm(37-1/8”)
**Height:** 106mm(4-1/4”)
**Depth:** 317mm(12-1/2”)
**Weight:** 4.0kg

**Control Interface**
**Keyboard Number of Keys:** 61
**Display Type:** LCD display
**Language:** English

Comment: what you have try so far ? you want to set it programmtically ? is this data coming from any loop ? could you please share the code if you have tried anything

Comment: Wrap the text in spans and set a bolding CSS rule to match. Or use the bold tag; but I think that's deprecated.

Comment: This is **HTML 101** stuff. Something you should know of.

Comment: And what has this question in common with PHP, JavaScript or HTML5, besides the tags and the title?

Comment: Plus, you have given us "NO CODE" whatsoever.

Comment: i will do a lot text. Every text 500-1000 words. Should be with PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong>Dimensions</strong><br>
<strong>Width:</strong> 940mm(37-1/8”)<br>
<strong>Height:</strong> 106mm(4-1/4”)<br>
<strong>Depth:</strong> 317mm(12-1/2”)<br>
<strong>Weight:</strong> 4.0kg<br>
```